# Common practice?

Tags: php, conditional-statements, shortcut, shorthand

I've been wondering whether this shorthand, if we may call it that, is an accepted practice of coding among pro PHP devs:

```
foo() && bar();
```

instead of

```
if( foo() ) {
    bar();
}
```

While IMO the single line code is much neater, I've not seen it being used anywhere.

Comment: I'd say if any, then `foo() and bar()` would be more common (or at least it should be (imo ;))). But I'm not a "pro" PHP developer...

Comment: It's fairly common in Bash and Perl scripts... and of course there's the ubiquitous `mysql_connect(...) or die()`, which falls in the same category I suppose.

Comment: You could say `if (foo()) bar();` if you want it on a single line. Or even `foo() ? bar() : null;`, if you want to. But besides being *clever* this is nothing but syntactic sugar. Say what conveys *meaning*, not what fits on a single line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a common practice among developers of a number of languages. There is technically nothing wrong with it, but judging by the number of times it shows up on StackOverflow, I'll go ahead and say that it is a "use only when it is the only thing which makes sense." Most people don't expect it.

That said, this is perfectly valid:

```
foo()?bar()?bat():zonk():baz();
```

As is

```
foo() && bar() && baz();
```

Just remember:

```
function foo(){return true;} 
function bar(){echo "bar";} 
function baz(){echo "baz";  return 2;} 
echo foo()||foo()?baz():baz(); // baz2
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I see nothing wrong with it. It's fairly widespread, so most PHP programmers will understand it just as well as they would understand the extended version, making it perfectly acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

The most important part is that you write code that is easy to read. Using function names like `foo()` and `bar()` for example are totally useless, so it's hard to say which one of the two you want to compare are better.

Next to that, the if example has some considerable flaws as well:

- `if` is a language construct, but you use it like a function.
- you add vertical space into the if condition. This can make things hard to read as spaces are influencing the visual focus.

An alternative suggestion would be:

```
if (foo()) {
```

But you wanted to compare the two: Code is always in it's context. And readable code uses it's context. Both of your suggestions can be valid, the key point is that you can read the meaning from the code already:

```
   conditionMet() && gotForIt();

   if (conditionMet()) goForIt();
```

Decide for yourself. Just don't mix from one line to the other, so keep one style through your whole code.

Answer (score 1):

`foo() && bar();` is a boolean expression, so it's wrong if you don't put it inside a boolean context (a condition like `if`, `while`, etc).

The code has to tell "the story" of the problem being solved, using this shortcut is not telling the story. It's an ugly hack, it's not elegant.

If you think about it as "neat", then you haven't yet reached **the point where code means ideas**, not code.